# Problema p:datePicker Primefeaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Hola estoy con un proyecto usando JSF y Primefaces.

El caso es que intento usar la etiqueta p:datePicker y no me la detecta, a la gente que le haya pasado lo mismo era por la versión que era antigua pero yo tengo la 6.2 la cual soporta dicha etiqueta.

Me dice esto:
The component library Primefaces does not contain component datePicker.

A sugrencia del compi esto es lo que he puesto:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        PrimeFaces.locales['es'] = {
            closeText: 'Cerrar',
            prevText: 'Anterior',
            nextText: 'Siguiente',
            monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
            dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab'],
            dayNamesMin: ['D', 'L', 'M', 'X', 'J', 'V', 'S'],
            weekHeader: 'Semana',
            firstDayOfWeek: 1,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: '',
            timeOnlyTitle: 'Sólo hora',
            timeText: 'Tiempo',
            hourText: 'Hora',
            minuteText: 'Minuto',
            secondText: 'Segundo',
            currentText: 'Fecha actual',
            ampm: false,
            month: 'Mes',
            week: 'Semana',
            day: 'Día',
            allDayText: 'Todo el día'
        };
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        function dateTemplateFunc(date) {
            return '<span style="background-color:' + ((date.day < 21 && date.day > 10) ? '#81C784' : 'inherit') + ';border-radius:50%;padding: .25em;width: 1.75em; height:1.75em; display:block;">' + date.day + '</span>';
        }
        //]]>
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .value {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</ui:define>
```

Y dentro del body

a parte de los demas campos del formulario esto

```
    <ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/template.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form>
                <f:event listener="#{registerView.validatePassword}" type="postValidate" />
                <p:messages id="messages" closable="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
                <p:panel header="Crear una nueva cuenta">
                    <h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="3">
```

demas etiquetas....

```
 <p:outputLabel for="fechaNacimiento" value="Fecha Nacimiento:" />
                            <p:datePicker id="fechaNacimiento" value="#{registerView.fechaNacimiento}" locale="es" monthNavigator="true" pattern="yyyy-MMM-dd"/>
</h:panelGrid>
                        <p:commandButton action="#{registerView.register}" update="grid" value="Regístrate!" icon="uiicon-pencil"/>

                    </p:panel>
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añade tu código para ver como tienes puesto `p:datePicker`

Comment: @MarioGuiber actualizado

Comment: creo que datepicker es a partir de la versión 7.0 de primefaces

Answer (score 0):

La versión 6.2 no contiene el component datePicker.

Tus opciones pasan por actualizar a la 6.2.14 o a la 7.

El cambio a la 6.2.14 debería ser el menos costoso en cuanto a migración/diferencias con tu versión actual, pero requiere licencia de PrimeFaces.

La 7 es de libre acceso, pero podría implicar más cambios para actualizar.